# Build LambdaExpression with Func<,> where returnType is IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a generic way of getting an EntityFramework object based on its own id without passing in a lambda expression as parameter to the method `GetById()`. For the code below the entity `T` is of type `Message`, is known to the class where `GetById()` is implemented and has a property `MessageId` along with several other properties. The `MessageId` name has been hard-coded in the example below as this is still experimental - extracting the id property name from `T` is quite easy to fix later.

I have been struggling to find a way to construct a simple `LambdaExpression` which has `IQueryable<T>` as parameter type and hope that someone would have a clue on how this could be done. The reason why I want `IQueryable<T>` is because my underlying channel factory provider requires this for more complex queries.

The line with `var exp = Expression.Lambda<...>` in the code below shows the expression function type definition which I want to end up with, but the line gives the exception:

> Expression of type System.Boolean cannot be used for return type IQueryable

That's because the body has the `Boolean` type while my expression parameter `queryParamtRet` is of type `IQueryable<Message>`. Further, if I change the body type to be an `IQueryable<Message>`, I'm not able to find the property `MessageId` since the type is no longer type `T` as `Message` but type `IQueryable<T>`.

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
    var queryParamLeft = Expression
        .Parameter(typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>), "o");
    var queryParamRet = Expression
        .Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<T>), "o");
    var entityFrameworkType = Expression
        .Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
    var queryProperty = Expression
        .PropertyOrField(entityFrameworkType, "MessageId");
    var body = Expression
        .Equal(queryProperty, Expression.Constant(id));
    var exp = Expression
        .Lambda<Func<System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>>(
            body,
            queryParamRet);

    var returnXml = DoWithChannel(channel
                        => channel.Load(serializer.Serialize(exp)));
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a step in your expression - if it was written as a LINQ statement in c# what would it look like? `dbSet.Where(o => o.MessageId == id)` maybe?

Comment: You are missing the `Expression.Call(Queryable.Where, Expression.Lambda<...>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR:  Write out code that you want to create an expression for, then deliberately create the expression, starting with any inner expressions before combining them into the outer expression.

---

If you write your intended code as a function, it would look something like this

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterADbSet(DbSet<T> dbSet)
{
    return Queryable.Where<T>(dbSet, o => o.MessageId == 34);
}
```

It has one input parameter of type `DbSet<T>`, an output of type `IQueryable<T>` and it calls `Queryable.Where<T>` with parameters of the dbSet variable and an expression.

Working from the outside in, you first need to build the expression to pass to the where clause.  You have already done that in your code.

Next you need to create a lambda expression for the where clause.

```
var whereClause = Expression.Equal(queryProperty, Expression.Constant(id));

var whereClauseLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereClause, entityFrameworkType);
```

Next, as the comments indicate, you need to use Expression.Call to create a body.

My end result with making your code work is below.

```
static Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>> WhereMethodExpression = v => v.Where(z => true);
static MethodInfo WhereMethod = ((MethodCallExpression)WhereMethodExpression.Body).Method;

public T GetById(int id)
{
    var queryParamLeft = Expression
        .Parameter(typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>), "dbSet");

    var entityFrameworkType = Expression
        .Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");

    var queryProperty = Expression
        .PropertyOrField(entityFrameworkType, "MessageId");

    var whereClause = Expression
        .Equal(queryProperty, Expression.Constant(id));

    var whereClauseLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereClause, entityFrameworkType);

    var body = Expression.Call(
        WhereMethod,
        queryParamLeft,
        whereClauseLambda
        );

    var exp = Expression
        .Lambda<Func<System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>>(
            body,
            queryParamLeft);

    var returnXml = DoWithChannel(channel
                        => channel.Load(serializer.Serialize(exp)));

}
```

1. I used an expression to fetch the MethodInfo object of `Queryable.Where<T>`
2. Your body expression needed `queryParamLeft` passed in.  queryParamRet is not needed